# How to deal with internal library functionality in dart

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I'm probably over complicating this.  But I have a library I'm making. It will have 2 parts, the external "anyone can play with these" things and the internal things.  It is my intention that the internal things stay relatively unexposed to try and keep the interface clean an easy to reason about.  So here is what I'm doing (tell me if this is crazy or not).

For external things, I have the library, and then everything that should be exposed as a "part" of that library.  For the internal things, I have have a separate "my_library_internal" library which has all of its classes as part of the internal library class.

Where things get weird.  The internal library imports the external library to all the internal library methods to use external library objects.  This eventually results in warnings from the compiler (though it does appear to compile just fine).

Is this the idiomatic way to do this or should I just make everything that deals with this library, internal or external, a part of it and not worry about over exposing the guts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in the [Important Concepts](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-concepts) page of the Dart documentation, the way it works is that:

> - Unlike Java, Dart doesn’t have the keywords `public`, `protected`, and `private`. If an identifier starts with an underscore (_), it’s private to its library. For details, see [the section called “Libraries and Visibility”](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#libraries).

So, put your internal types in the same library as the public types, and prefix them with an underscore `_`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems perfectly fine, and shouldn't even need to cause warnings.

If you only have one library, you can use library private members and put them all in the same library (`var _private = foo;`), but if you have more than one exposed library that share "private" functionality, having a shared "hidden" library is the simplest way to do it.

You can't *really* hide the shared hidden library - if someone wants to import it, they can, but then, they can probably do much more damage using dart:mirrors if that is what they want.

Comment: This works, but I like Jean's answer slightly better.  Putting a `_` in front of the types I don't want to expose accomplished what I was shooting for.